# Can not authenticate in Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-authentication

I made an application in android in which I set Facebook authentication on button click.
But when I click that button it comes back to my activity.

I know that problem is that : I can not log in to Facebook because I have already signed in with Facebook app in my device.

Then my question is how can I log in separately in my Android app and Facebook app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I solved the problem using this:

Open Facebook.java provided by facebook sdk and then i had changes like this:

```
public void authorize(Activity activity, String[] permissions,
            int activityCode, final DialogListener listener) {

        boolean singleSignOnStarted = false;

        mAuthDialogListener = listener;

      /*  // Prefer single sign-on, where available.
        if (activityCode >= 0) {
            singleSignOnStarted = startSingleSignOn(activity, mAppId,
                    permissions, activityCode);
        }
        // Otherwise fall back to traditional dialog.
        if (!singleSignOnStarted) {*/
            startDialogAuth(activity, permissions);
       // }
    }
```

Finally i can able to login in both app in my device

Answer (score 0):

if u have used fb sdk than in class **FacebookConnector**  change the  **login** method as shown below

```
public void login() {
    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this.activity, this.permissions,-1,new LoginDialogListener());
    }
}
```

may it works